# How can I get value from dictionary object?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a code:

```
public ActionResult _getprice([FromBody] JsonElement selectedOptionsJson)
{
    var selectedOptions = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>(
        selectedOptionsJson.GetRawText());
    int ProductId = 0;
    var dictionaryOptions = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    foreach (var property in selectedOptions.EnumerateObject())
    {
        dictionaryOptions[property.Name] = GetObjectFromJsonElement(property.Value);
        if (property.Name == "productId")
        {
            ProductId = Convert.ToInt32(GetObjectFromJsonElement(property.Value));
        }
    }     
    var secondDictionary = dictionaryOptions.ElementAtOrDefault(1).Value;
    return Json(1);
}
```

`seconddictionary` contains: [image: Screenshot]

How can I get key value present in `seconddictionary` in `List<keyvalue>` properties key and value?

```
public class KeyValue
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

It is dynamic variant.

Comment: Why `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>`? Either deserialize to a specific type or use `JsonDocument.Parse`. Calling a public method `_getPrice` isn't a great idea either. It violates *all* naming conventions and breaks routing conventions

Comment: Why do you have a `KeyValue` inside a dictionary representing a `KeyValuePair<string, object>` ? is that intentional?

Comment: you should almost never access a dictionary by position (`ElementAtOrDefault`) - dictionary is *unordered*; you normally access it by *key*, via `[key]` or `TryGetValue(key, out var value)`, unless you're trying to list all items

Comment: Use a `List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>` if you need to access items via index.

Comment: Never mind that a `GET` can't have a body. This looks like an attempt to port code from another language into ASP.NET Core. ASP.NET Core can already deserialize JSON to objects though. If you create a method `[HttpPost] public Price(PriceDTO price){...}` you'll be able to POST to `.../price` and have ASP.NET Core deserialize the JSON payload to an object

Comment: Why is it a JsonElement and not a real class with real properties with the real options you want to surface here? I don't see that a client can send any option and your server magically can do the right thing with it. Or is "option" just a misnomer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you need. You can use Linq to do so:

```
List<KeyValue> keyValueList = dict.Select(kvp => new KeyValue{
Key = kvp.Key,
Value = kvp.Value}).ToList();
```

You should have a list with every objects in your dictionary.